# Have problem with multi-line string in javascript

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
alert('foo\
         bar'
)
```

But this is causing syntax error:

```
t='test';
alert('<tr><td><b>' + t + '</b></td>\ 
                    <td></td><td>')
```

error is:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

They two should be the same thing, why the first one works, while the second fails?

Comment: Maybe you have extra spaces after the back-slash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trailing space after your backslash in the second example.

Comment: By the way, it may be worth pointing out that trailing whitespace in any piece of code is pretty much universally frowned upon in the programming community. Many editors will highlight it as an error regardless of the context. (The only exception to this is lines consisting *entirely* of whitespace.)

Comment: @J.J. No, I don’t see any trailing spaces in the first example.